# Openshift + Meteor = listen EACCES?

Tags: node.js, unix, meteor, redhat, openshift

I deployed Meteor.js on a Node 0.6 + Mongo 2.2 Openshift cartridge with a custom Node 0.8.24 installed in the data dir (sort of like [this tutorial](https://www.openshift.com/content/add-meteorjs-support#comment-25174)).

I do set the right ports before calling the app. My code in `server.js` looks like that:

```
// Setup env
process.env.ROOT_URL = "http://" + (process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS || "localhost");
process.env.MONGO_URL = (process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL + process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME) || "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
process.env.PORT = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8000;
process.env.IP = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '0.0.0.0';

// Show connection details on startup
console.log("MONGO_URL IS: " + process.env.MONGO_URL);
console.log("ROOT_URL IS: " + process.env.ROOT_URL);
console.log("PORT: " + process.env.PORT);
console.log("IP: " + process.env.IP);

require(require('path').join(__dirname, 'main.js'));
```

Then, when I `rhc app restart myappname` the app, I get:

```
> node server.js

MONGO_URL IS: mongodb://<login>:<pass>@127.5.x.x:27017/<myapp>
ROOT_URL IS: http://<myappname>-<mydomain>.rhcloud.com
PORT: 8080
IP: 127.5.x.x

events.js:71
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:893:19)
    at listen (net.js:932:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1006:9)
    at dns.js:72:18
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:245:9)
npm info <mydomain>@0.0.1 Failed to exec start script
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

`main.js` is he regular entry point for my Meteor app.

The env settings look like the right ones. Why do I keep getting this `EACCESS`?

Comment: Here's a blog related to deploying Meteor:  https://www.openshift.com/blogs/cloudy-with-a-chance-of-meteorjs    Can you take a look to see if it helps?

Comment: Yeah I also tried that one and ended up with the same result :(

Comment: could you post your package.json and your app entry point file (server.js by default for openshift)?

Comment: I made some updates to the quickstart, but there may be some lingering issues related to how the 'fibers' package is loaded.  Feel free to help test / debug and file issues here: https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-meteorjs-quickstart/issues

Comment: I think having someone from ops install meteor, meteorite, gyp, and fibers (globally) is the real solution for this issue.  Then we could build an [action hook](https://www.openshift.com/developers/deploying-and-building-applications) that does the bundle step automatically as a part of the application build process.

Comment: C9 is running on top of openshift. If this works, there should be a way to do the same on openshift as well: http://c9install.meteor.com/install.html